# Configuration Error in asp mvc 2 project. MvcContrib, Version=2.0.96.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-2, mvccontrib

**Could not load file or assembly 'MvcContrib, Version=2.0.96.0' or one of its dependencies.**

I am getting this error on my project which is created by some else and I am debugging this on my computer.

I think I know what the problem is, I need to get `MvcContrib, Version=2.0.96.0` but I am working on `visual studio 2008` and there is no package library installer on it.

How to do this ??

This is how the message comes up.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'MvcContrib, Version=2.0.96.0' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

```
Line 46:   <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,        PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
Line 47:    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
Line 48:         <add assembly="MvcContrib, Version=2.0.96.0"/>
Line 49:            </assemblies>
Line 50:        </compilation>
```

Comment: What is the solution to this problem ? Please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download form here: [MVC 2 - 2.0.96.0](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/releases) & refer the dll in your application.

Comment: I did that but it still giving me the same error, I think I might be missing some other DLL`s ?